# Привет! Почему-то не могу растянуть навигационное меню по всему окну, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: html, css

Я новичок в HTML кодинге, пытаюсь сам изучить сие чудо, возникает много вопросов, на которое нет ответов, был бы рад появлению наставника, с которым можно было бы подробно пообщаться о некоторых аспектах.Насчет вопроса.... У меня не получается растянуть навигационное меню на весь экран. Код прилагается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    body {
    font-family: 'Hurricane', cursive;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;

}
.container {
    width: 1250px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
margin-bottom: 64px;
color: #FFC815;
font-size: 24px;
flex-basis: auto;
flex-grow: 1;
}

.header-row {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
padding-top: 47px;
padding-bottom: 26px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
.header-nav {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 90px;
    align-self: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mafia Lounge2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-row">
            <nav>
            <ul class="header-nav">
                <li class="header-nav">
                    <a href="" class="header-nav">Главная</a>
                    <a href="" class="header-nav">Корзина</a>
                    <a href="" class="header-nav">Отзывы</a>
                    <span class="number"><a href="tel:+7 919 900-40-05">+7 919 900-40-05</a></span>
                </li>
            </ul>       



</nav>

        </div>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добавьте html в пример

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    width: 1250px;
    .....
```

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то скорее всего пробела в `width: 1250px;`, вот больше 1250 пикселей и не растягивается. Задай там `width: 100%;`